# KOA not functioning with pm2

Tags: node.js, koa, pm2

I've tried running with --node-args="--harmony" and --next-gen-js and run into the same error.  Has anyone else run into this problem before?

> app-0 (err):     at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12) app-0
>
> (err):     at Function.
>
> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/pm2/node_modules/pmx/lib/transaction.js:62:21)
>
> app-0 (err):     at Module.require (module.js:365:17) app-0 (err):
>
> at require (module.js:384:17) app-0 (err):     at Object.
>
> (/home/safeuser/mana-match/app.js:1:73) app-0 (err):     at
>
> Module._compile (module.js:460:26) app-0 (err):
>
> /home/safeuser/mana-match/node_modules/koa/lib/application.js:179
>
> app-0 (err): function *respond(next) { app-0 (err):          ^ app-0
>
> (err): SyntaxError: Unexpected token * app-0 (err):     at
>
> exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:73:16) app-0 (err):     at
>
> Module._compile (module.js:443:25) app-0 (err):     at
>
> Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10) app-0 (err):     at
>
> Module.load (module.js:355:32) app-0 (err):     at
>
> Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12) app-0 (err):     at
>
> Function.
>
> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/pm2/node_modules/pmx/lib/transaction.js:62:21)
>
> app-0 (err):     at Module.require (module.js:365:17) app-0 (err):
>
> at require (module.js:384:17) app-0 (err):     at Object.
>
> (/home/safeuser/mana-match/app.js:1:73) app-0 (err):     at
>
> Module._compile (module.js:460:26)

Comment: Works fine for me, try to kill pm2 with: pm2 kill and run it again just with the --node-args="--harmony"

Comment: Thanks man, seemed to help it.. although it still restarted a couple times before staying put.. weird.